# Variable output in Jupyter-Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In already prepared Jupyter notebook I have the next simple example:

`IN:
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
a
OUT:
array([0, 1, 2, 3])`

But when I'm trying to copy&execute it in the PyCharm editor I don't see anything(code run without problems). Is it some kind of special output in Jupyter?

Comment: You mean you created a `.py` file using the Pycharm editor and then clicked the `run` button?

Comment: Just use print(a). Jupyter Notebook automatically prints the last used variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
print(a)
```

use print function to show output in pycharm

Comment: Yeah, it works, but output a little bit different - just [0 1 2 3]